# Python adding a value to buffer

Tags: python

I am having an issue with using multiple values from different pieces of code.
I have 4 python files which need to communicate back and forth different values.

I have a `rotary_encoder`, a `webserver`, a `X11(gtk)` and `rotary_Handler`.

`rotary_Handler` checks a physical rotary encoder and creates events then passes that to `rotary_encoder`, Then `rotary_encoder` sets Output and Pressed variables.

Webserver sets a len(outfiles) variable and gets the Output and Pressed variables.

`rotary encode`r also gets to `len(outfiles)` variable and uses it to reset the output variable `(if output > lef(outfiles): outfiles = 0)`.

`x11(gtk)` gets the Pressed variable.

The `X11` and `webserver` must remain separate and both require variables from the `rotary_encoder` file and all are endless code (will run until manually stopped).

I was thinking about putting the 3 variables into a memory buffer and then grab the buffer into the files I need. I have never used buffers or anything before so if anyone could get me started or provide different methods of importing these variables i would appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

`rotary_encoder` uses RPi.GPIO module and collects I/O data from the GPIO pins

`rotary_Handler` uses RPi.GPIO and gets events from `rotary_encoder`.

`webserver` is a python-Flask webserver creating 2 pages ('index' and '/receiving') uses pyserial to transmit data across the GPIO RX/TX pins. Also gets a list of files using Glob.

`x11(gtk)` is x11 wrapper for a python script (using xinit), python script is Python-GTK and webkit to create a simple webbrowser.

When I turn the rotary encoder I am selecting a value from the Glob list (a html file) and setting the index of the server to a new webpage. When a new webpage is set i need to restart the flask webserver, refresh the python-GTK webbrowser and keep the rotary encoder running without changing its value.

Also the Glob list has a max value, I need to tell the rotary encoder that when it hits that max value to default back to 0 and continue. The Glob list can have 1 or 1 million files depending on the task.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 3 procesess - one obtaining IO-based values, and two working with this data. If that's correct, the solution is to use some form of IPC mechanism. there is a plethora of them, especially on unix. I would e.g. go for named pipes. Simple, robust, fast.

Comment: could you posible make a small example and add it as an answer. i remember running into issues with pipe and looping code.

Comment: I guess I can try & conjure something up, but I also think you should rephrase your question accordingly. Your current question is rather confused & I had to guess a lot. So once you've done that, I'll try & come up with something. Alternatively, use a different IPC technology such as nanomsg. It's actually very nice, and if you have it as package for your system, you just use it's ipc-mechanism and be good.

Comment: I can provid a nanomsg example as well, but it would be good to know if that works for you.

Comment: im having difficulty editing the question as at this point I'm not sure what im trying to use, i had a quick test with threading but that failed as the treads dont stop so the next thread doesn't start. any examples or documentation you can provide would be extremely helpful. Just as a quick note, i am using python-Flask, gtk and xinit (X11).

Comment: I think you should try & outline more precisely what you want. How many actual processes, distinguish these from "python files" (one program can be composed of many python modules, but is still one process), this `X11(gtk)` thing is confusing, and what and why this restarting business - which might be worth a different question actually.

Comment: x11(gtk) is basically an x11 wrapper to display a pythonGTK code to the screen, using xinit.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you have a rotary encoder that selects a file shown from a list of files. Where does the need for all that restarting come from? I fail to see why you can't use multi-threading to serve, talk to GPIO and show a webrowser. Also your requirement to "tell the rotary encoder when it has hit the limit" is uneccessary, even in your current design. All you need is to take the rotary encoder value modulo the actual number of items - then the wrap-around will be automatic.